# How to list all the bucket types in riak?

Tags: erlang, riak

Using Riak Client(erlang), I can list all the buckets of the default bucket type. But how can I list all the bucket types? Or If I can't do this by the client, how can I find out about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For v2.1.4, [`riak-admin bucket-type list`](https://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.1.4/using/admin/riak-admin/#bucket-type) is what you are looking for.

Other sub-commands for `riak-admin bucket-type` (taken from the riak docs at an earlier revision) include:

```
Command    Action                                  Form
create     create or modify a bucket type          create <type> <json>  
           before activation

activate   activate a bucket type                  activate <type> 

list       list all currently available bucket 
           types and their activation status       list

status     display the status and properties       status <type> 
           of a specific bucket type

update     update a bucket type after activation   update <type> <json>
```