# how to get all bucket types in riak using http get

Tags: riak, riak-2i

I know how to list all bucket types using command line .reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30785431/how-to-list-all-the-bucket-types-in-riak

But I need it using HTTP call

Comment: can't understand what u mean. I  just need http request. like for list all buckets , we use command "http://127.0.0.1:10018/buckets?buckets=true"

Comment: Unfortunately, it's currently not supported AFAIK, unlike buckets and keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to list bucket types via HTTP. I can suggest two options:

1. Wrap the `riak-admin bucket-types list` command in a simple Web service and expose it via HTTP.
2. Install the experimental [Riak Explorer](https://github.com/basho-labs/riak_explorer), point it to your cluster, and use the *bucket_types* endpoint to list bucket types. For example, `curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:9000/explore/clusters/default/bucket_types` should give you something like

```
{
    "bucket_types": [{
        "id": "default",
        "props": {
            "active": true,
            "allow_mult": true,
            "basic_quorum": false,
            "big_vclock": 50,
            "chash_keyfun": "{riak_core_util,chash_std_keyfun}",
            "dvv_enabled": false,
            "dw": "quorum",
            "last_write_wins": false,
            "linkfun": "{modfun,riak_kv_wm_link_walker,mapreduce_linkfun}",
            "n_val": 3,
            "notfound_ok": true,
            "old_vclock": 86400,
            "postcommit": [],
            "pr": 0,
            "precommit": [],
            "pw": 0,
            "r": "quorum",
            "rw": "quorum",
            "small_vclock": 50,
            "w": "quorum",
            "write_once": false,
            "young_vclock": 20
        }
    }],
    "links": {
        "self": "/explore/clusters/default/bucket_types"
    }
}
```